# ruby JSON parser that lets you filter keys?

Tags: json, ruby

I'm hoping for a Ruby JSON parsing library that lets me say: If you scan to `randomkeyname`, please don't allocate memory for its value(s) and just skip it while parsing.

I'm looking into fat JSON payloads from an API we don't control, and the main downside I want to fight is memory usage when parsing these ginormous payloads.

Anyone know this offhand? I've looked at stdlib, OJ, and fast_jsonparser.

Comment: You can probably use [json-streamer](https://github.com/thisismydesign/json-streamer) for that

Comment: @Fravadona "no ongoing development" might be a cause for minor concern.